# postfix configuration and Received from

Tags: postfix, smtp

Having some trouble here. My server has 3 IP addresses and this is my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
46.38.235.226 brian.smares.de brian
46.38.238.199 stewie.smares.de stewie
46.38.238.137 mail.smares.de mail
```

postfix is set up with

```
inet_interfaces = localhost, $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.smares.de
mydomain = smares.de
myorigin = $mydomain
```

If I send an e-mail, the source reads

```
Received: from mail.smares.de (pelikansal.at. [46.38.235.226])
```

pelikansal.at is the rDNS target for 46.38.235.226.

What I don't understand is why that IP is being used instead of 46.38.238.137. My server's FQDN is brian.smares.de which would map to the 226 address, but is that the cause?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible solution

When sending an email, the parameter used to control outgoing IP address was [`smtp_bind_address`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address). So you should explicitly set parameter `smtp_bind_address` to one IP address.

---

### Explanation

Your configuration above, you already modified [`inet_interfaces`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces) parameter. It only set which IP Address that postfix will **receive** mails on.

However, parameter `inet_interfaces` can also affect `smtp_bind_address` if these three conditions were sufficient:

1. `smtp_bind_address` is empty (by default)
2. `inet_interfaces` only have **ONE** IPv4 IP Address
3. `inet_interfaces` list wasn't loopback.

When it happened, `smtp_bind_address` = `$inet_interfaces`.

Because you have setup two IP address in `inet_interfaces`, then `smtp_bind_address` was still empty. In that case, [smtp client uses 0.0.0.0 as its IP address and 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY) means the kernel will chose the IP address based on where the packet goes](http://narkive.com/4ocP9FyJ:7.53.2). From [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726845/ip-address-when-multiple-nics-are-involved) by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), he says

> If the client does not bind to a specific IP, or it binds to INADDR_ANY, the socket will use the first IP it finds that has an available route to the server IP being connected to.

So, in your case it's understandable that kernel choose 46.38.238.137 to make outgoing connection.