# Does inet_interfaces bind outgoing mail when more than one address is specified?

Tags: postfix

Question: When specifying 2 or more address for the `inet_interfaces` directive, will postfix still bind outgoing mail to ***one*** of them?

The postfix docs state:

> When inet_interfaces specifies just one IPv4 and/or IPv6 address that is not a loopback address, the Postfix SMTP client will use this address as the IP source address for outbound mail.

Due to the need for a loopback address I need to be able to bind to either 127.0.0.1 or my WAN address depending on mail destination.  My current setting is:

```
inet_interfaces = 23.45.67.89, [2600:1234::1234:5678:abcd:abcd], 127.0.0.1
```

Previously I had used `smtp_bind_address` and `smtp_bind_address6` but was causing problems since postfix needs to access loopback for local mail delivery.

Also, I do in fact have 5 static IPv4 addresses for this server, hence the desire to only use one of them.  Since the docs state `just one IPv4 and/or IPv6` I'm unsure whether specifying all three will ensure that outgoing mail is bound to anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: When specifying 2 or more address for the inet_interfaces directive, will postfix still bind outgoing mail to one of them?

**No**

Parameter `inet_interfaces` is consulted *if `inet_interfaces` specifies just one IPv4 and/or IPv6 address that is not a loopback address*. When `inet_interfaces` doesn't satisfy that, postfix will use treat `smtp_bind_address` as default. There are no docs mentioned that `smtp_bind_address` will use one of address specify in `inet_interfaces`

Source: [Postfix source code, especially in smtp_connect.c](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/smtp/smtp_connect.c#L252) and postfix documentation.

Comment: thanks, and if `smtp_bind_address` is not specified?  Is it just a coin toss at this point or will the addresses specified in `inet_interfaces` have any effect on which one is used?

Comment: The socket will use the first IP it finds that has an available route to the server IP being connected to. See [postfix configuration and Received from](http://serverfault.com/a/676158/218590)